# Why is there a "one" before "hundred", "thousand", etc. but not "ten"?

Tags: grammar, etymology, numbers

As the title says, why is there a "one" before "hundred", before "thousand", and so on, but not before "ten"?

This seems shared between *some* languages, including Chinese (10 = 十 = ten, 100 = 一百 = one hundred), but not others, like French (10 = dix = ten, 100 = cent = hundred).

Comment: Although it's not an answer, I would say 'a hundred' in preference to 'one hundred'.

Comment: Let me ask a follow-up question: in pronouncing numbers such as 150, is it ever acceptable to omit the "one" and just say "hundred fifty"? (It certainly is in German, and German speakers often carry this over to English.)

Answer (score 19):

The simplest explanation, which does not really delve into linguistics at all, is that "ten" is not a unit that you use in multiples.  That is, "20" is not spoken of as "two-tens", "50" is not spoken of as "five-tens".  Thus there is no need for the disambiguation of specifying "one ten".  (French seems to have decided that if you don't specify a count, "one" is assumed, as you don't say "un cent", "un mille", "un milliard", etc.)

Comment: Heh, 18 seconds faster than I was according to my clock. *sigh +1*

Answer (score 7):

This may not be quite the answer you were looking for, but the reason is because English has special words for *twenty*, *thirty* and so on. There is no such equivalent for *hundred* or *thousand* or even *dozen* which leaves us with saying *two thousand* or *four dozen*.

Answer (score 0):

The similarity to Chinese is probably a complete coincidence. My gut feeling as to why this is like it is in English is that, in some strange sense, "hundred" is more like "dozen"... not a number, per se, but a (dimensionless) unit of measure.

From the Wikipedia page on dimensionless quantities:

"Units of amount such as the dozen and the gross are also dimensionless."

Just to set the record straight.

Comment: *hundred* and *dozen* are most definitely numbers...

Comment: @whoa: Calling them _numbers_ may be misleading in the sense that we do not count from nine, ten, eleven, dozen. Also, compare the dictionary entries for _twelve_ and _dozen_.

Comment: @MrHen, The fact that we do not use dozen in place of 12 when counting is irrelevant. I don't count 1, 2, 3, pi, 4... That doesn't make pi any less of a number.

Comment: @whoa: It is relevant in that it was an example of where _dozen_ isn't really considered a number: All of math. `2 * 6 = 12` When choosing to write it out, you would write "two times six equals twelve" not "two times six equals dozen." You _could_ say "two time six equals a dozen" but now you have an article in there. If you feel comfortable calling that a number, so be it. I was just pointing out that it may be misleading to consider _dozen_ the same kind of number as _twelve_ much like _a six_ isn't the same "kind" of "number" as _six_ or _6_.

Comment: @mrhen, That's preposterous. "Jimmy has a dozen eggs, he gives Sally half, how many does he have left?". Answer: 12 * 1/2 = 6. According to your logic, 'half' wouldn't be considered a number either? A dozen is a real number, even in Math...

Comment: @whoa: I am simply trying to point out the difference between _dozen_ and _twelve_ with regards to their qualifications for the label "number". There _is_ a difference and just calling _dozen_ a "number" may be misleading. And yes, it would be just as misleading to refer to "a half" as a number. Or "a whole" or "first". Do they technically qualify as numbers? You tell me. My point is that even if they do, there is a difference between those and numbers like 9, 10, _pi_, _i_.

Comment: @whoabackoff: So, according to your definition of number, pair times pair times few equals dozen? Nevermind that you are ignoring the fact that pair, few, dozen, score, hundred, gross, etc. are commonly used as units of measure.

Comment: @whoabackoff: Radians and degrees are dimensionless units of measure. Try consulting the Wikipedia entry on "dimensionless quantity" for a discussion of "dimensionless units". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionless_quantity.

Comment: @thom, I am simply trying to point out that dozen is considered a number, even in math. Don't confuse units of measurement (e.g., kg, m, s, K, V) with dimensionless quantities (e.g., pi, e, golden ratio, dozen (aka 12), gross (aka 144)) and indefinite and fictitious numbers (e.g., few, eleventy, some, bunch, thirty-something). While 'dozen' may be a dimensionless unit of measure, 'hundred' is not. And your answer remains incorrect.

Comment: Did you read the Wikipedia article? Clearly I'm not the only person alive who thinks calling "dozen" a "dimensionless unit of measure" is acceptable. If you accept this Wikipedia page to be at all authoritative, I don't see how you can come to any other conclusion than that you are incorrect in this matter.

Comment: This might be why teachers in schools tell their students not to cite Wikipedia...